# Android Studio 2.3.2 update - SDK and NDK problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3

This issues showed up immediately after updating *Android Studio* to *V2.3.2*

1. **SDK** Manager stand alone interface not opening, neither  inside Android studio.
2. Problem in **NDK** Path (not fully understand what NDK is and whats exactly the problem loading it)
3. building **`Gradle`** when creating new project takes ages.

   Question is: *How* to solve these problems? *What* caused it when updating IDE? *What* is NDK and the use of it?

Comment: Please specify your OS: is it Windows? Please check that your Android Studio and Android SDK don't have spaces in their paths (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Android Studio` would be a very bad idea). Regarding NDK, you can ignore it if you don't use it. Think about it as an add-on to Android SDK that lets you use C++ in your app.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, and I got what you said about NDK (y).. but I know this *spaces* thing and I don't have spaces in my path to android sdk, plus I tried to open the stand alone SDK .exe file.. still not opening!

Comment: As in `sdkmanager.exe`? That's a command line application. For the GUI you have to go through Studio.

Comment: Also, could you update your question to include the error messages? It's really not clear what went wrong.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't show up an error message.. it just appear and disappear instantly